# R script on premise data gateway

Tags: r, powerbi

I have created a report that read data from OData source, SQL Server and R.
R script read the data from an OData source.
Refresh works fine on my computer.

I want to share my work with my colleague and publish the report and use our On Premise Data Gateway, but I keep getting an error that data gateway is not configured correctly. If I use my personal gateway on my computer, everything works fine.

Any idea why On Premise Gateway is not working?

Comment: You should show your gateway configuration. What is different about the setup on your computer?  [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to stand corrected, but it's my understanding that R Scripts are not a supported data source for an Enterprise On Premise Data Gateway.

I imagine Microsoft are worried about taking on the intense compute demands generated by R within their cloud. The Personal Gateway keeps your machine doing all the R processing.